# Why is this nested SQL code so slow

Tags: sql-server, adodb

Using ADODB recordset with SQL server 2016 - This code is running **much** slower than if I just do the select query and then do the aggregation manually by looping through the recordset.. any ideas why?

```
SELECT SUM(wk1) AS wk1, SUM(wk2) AS wk2, SUM(wk3) AS wk3
    , SUM(recCount) AS recCount, MIN(Segment) AS Segment, Bucket
FROM (
    SELECT *, 1 AS recCount, NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Bucket
    FROM [Data]
    WHERE (1 = 1 AND [Area] = 'EAST') AND Segment = 2
    ) AS q
GROUP BY Bucket
```

Comment: In SSMS, CTRL-L will give you the query plan and also suggest indexes. What do you see?

Comment: Thanks Nick - I'm calling SQL server from a connection string within VBA code.. can I still use SSMS?

Comment: Yes. Install SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), connect to the server, paste that query into it and press CTRL-L. How many records are in `[Data]` ? Indexes generally only get useful after say 20,000 records or so (depending on many factors)

Comment: Thank you - I will try doing that from now on.  It seems that the `ORDER BY NEWID()` piece was doing another subquery which was the cause of the problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been the

```
NTILE(8) OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())
```

piece.  If I instead use

```
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) % 8) + 1
```

it seems to go much faster.